# Find total number of form and field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

There are multiple form on one html page which is created dynamically using ckeditor.

The requirement is to get total number of form and its name and also, in each form all the element name.

using that data, i have to call some API call with that name.

all using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USING JQUERY

```
$("form").each(function() {
        // apply logic here to find name etc

     }
```

Number of iterations here means number of forms in your page

USING JAVASCRIPT ONLY

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName("form")
for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
 //logic here
}
```

Comment: thanks...
its so silly sometime you will forget simplest thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.getElementsByTagName("form");` to get all forms. With each form you could then just get the `name` attribute.